# Launching devenv from git-bash gives build error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, batch-file, visual-c++, git-bash

I need to launch a build of my solution from gitbash. I am on visual studio 2010 running with the VS2003 toolset.
For that I call a .bat file which builds the solution from the devenv.exe switch command.

Running the bat file on its own is fine. However, running it from gitbash fails the build.

bat file:

```
"C:\...pathToDevenv...\IDE\devenv.exe" MySolution.sln /Build "Debug" /out BuildReport.log
```

call from git-bash:

```
./compileMySolution.bat
```

I get this error:

```
error MSB6001: Invalid command line switch for "CL.exe". Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'HOME'  Key being added: 'home'

Build FAILED.
```

I tried to set a home environment variable but failed.
I found no clue in the file Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.v71.targets(309,5).
Can someone help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I just unset the HOME variable in the shell and set it in the .bat file.